# How to calculate planar density of a face /plane of crystal with cation and anions?

Tags: solid-state-chemistry

Planar density is given by numer of atoms in plane /plane area  .

Suppose I want to calculate
planar density of 100, 101 and 111 planes of Nacl. Radius of Na+ and Cl- ions is 0.086 nm and 0.126 nm.Na+ are present at octahedral voids and cl- at FCC but the problem which I am facing is that I cannot add simply the number of atoms in given face/plane  for calulation of numer of atoms(zeff) as sizes of cation and anion  will be diffrent .What should I do??